# AS3 - Accessing class information through variable

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

At the moment I have a class that requires information from another class, but which class has to be determined at runtime based on other variables.

Effectively, I need my class BUTTON.as to be able to access GUN(1-9).as, without already knowing what number it will be.

The code that I assumed would work is this:

```
public function enableButton(shortcut:int):void{
        trace(ID)
        dtf_ammo.text = gun[ID].ammo
        refreshThis(shortcut, true)
        this.alpha = 1
        isActive = true
    }
```

ID is the number of the class (in this case, gun1).

The following does work:

```
public function enableButton(shortcut:int):void{
        trace(ID)
        dtf_ammo.text = gun1.ammo
        refreshThis(shortcut, true)
        this.alpha = 1
        isActive = true
    }
```

However, as there are 9 guns and only 1 class for the button I need to be able to use this ID variable to access functions within.

Is this possible, and if not is there a way to do what I'm trying to do here?

Comment: Are you attempting to access Class static variables? Instance variables?

Comment: I am attempting to access static.     public static var ammo:int = 999

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to access static properties of a class whose name is only known at runtime, you can use the following code.

```
getDefinitionByName("gun" + i).ammo
```

`getDefinitionByName` returns the Class object representing the class named by the String passed in. That Class object contains references to all of the static properties of the class.

Comment: This gives me an error for some reason, despite having "gun1.as" open and knowing it work: ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable gun1 is not defined.
 at global/flash.utils::getDefinitionByName()
 at src.actionbar::button/enableButton()

Comment: If it helps, the gun1-9 classes are not in the same folder as where this is called, they are in src.wepaons.gun1-9. I'm not really understanding why it's saying that gun1 is not defined.

Comment: @Kevin Make sure that either A: You import all of the gun# classes or B: you fully resolve the class name with the package name (weapons.gun#)

Comment: I have done that and I would assume it would work, given how the above solution does which also calls the classes by simply "gun1" "gun2". Even doing trace(getDefinitionByName("gun1")) returns the same error.

Comment: Solved it by doing the following: trace(getDefinitionByName("src.weapons.gun"+ID))

Answer (score 0):

You said the 2nd block of code is working. So if you create and array say

```
 var gun:Array = new Array( gun1, gun2,gun3,gun4,gun5,gun6,gun7,gun8,gun9 )
 //gun1 to gun9 , being the instances of the Gun class
public function enableButton(shortcut:int):void{
        trace(ID)
        dtf_ammo.text = gun[ID].ammo
        refreshThis(shortcut, true)
        this.alpha = 1
        isActive = true
    }
```

So, the function enableButton would work fine.

Comment: This worked, but it was to my understanding that you could not access static functions through arrays. I guess I mis-understood.

Comment: It's not array. It's an instance, as an array value. 
And yes, you cannot access a static function via an instance. You need to use a class name directly. So in case class name is Gun, then use Gun.ammo  ( it would otherwise give out compiler error )
Alternatively, as you said, there are 9 guns, then you may also use a function Gun.getGunInstance( <id> ).